# Genetic modifications to produce blue hair

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, epigenetics, hair, color

The following animals are known to produce blue pigmentation:

- [*Linckia laevigata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linckia_laevigata) (blue star, [study](https://doi.org/10.1016/0305-0491(89)90090-4) reveals blue carotenoprotein, *linkiacyanin*)
- [*Nessaea batesii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nessaea_batesii) (obrina olivewing, [study](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dick-Vane-Wright/publication/279189923_The_coloration_identification_and_phylogeny_of_Nessaea_butterflies_Lepidoptera_Nymphalidae/links/5772517908aeef01a0b627e2/The-coloration-identification-and-phylogeny-of-Nessaea-butterflies-Lepidoptera-Nymphalidae.pdf) reveals blue pterobilin pigment)
- [*Synchiropus splendidus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchiropus_splendidus) (mandarin dragonet, [study](https://doi.org/10.2108/zsj.12.811) reveals blue chromatophores ("cyanophores") and blue organelles ("cyanosomes"), but "the chemical nature of blue pigment remains to be determined")
- [*Synchiropus picturatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picturesque_dragonet) (picturesque dragonet, ibid.)

Given:

- Alpha-keratin is a fibrous structural protein of mammalian hair.
- Human hair is pigmented by eumelanin and pheomelanin.
- Eumelanin is associated with black or brown hair.
- Pheomelanin is associated with red or blond hair.
- The ratio of eumelanin to pheomelanin determines colour.
- MC1R provides instructions for making a protein called the melanocortin 1 receptor, which is a key gene for regulating hair colour.
- Keratin genes are found in chromosomes 12 and 17.
- The MC1R gene is found in chromosome 16.

What biological structures would have to be modified (or introduced) to produce pigmented blue hair in humans?

First example: Adding carotenoids to human hair (made from keratin) could be directed to deposit lipid droplets (fat molecules) within the cells of the hair follicles. As cells exit the follicle, the lipid solvent dissolves, leaving the carotenoid pigment dispersed throughout keratin that was genetically modified to offer a larger binding site for the blue protein. Intermingling yellow carotenoids and linckiacyanin at various ratios thereby provides a spectrum of blue hues.

Second example: Create a new cyanosomes organelle responsible for producing blue pigment that latches onto the eumelanin receptor. Change the epigenome for the MC1R gene to modify eumelanin with cyanophores produced by the organelle, such as by reprogramming the keratinocytes that regulate the function of melanocytes.